# TS2322: Type 'Todo[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Todo[]'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Todo[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, declaration

I have two questions regards to the code below. The questions I have are commented after the lines of the code that I have an issue with.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Todo{
  id: number,
  content: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let todo of todos">{{ todo.content }}</li>
    </ul>
    <pre>{{ todos | json }}</pre>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  todos: Todo[] = []; //Why do I need to initialize it everytime? when I tried to just declare the variable, it throws an error.
  url = 'http://localhost:3000/todos';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.http.get<Todo[]>(this.url, {observe: 'response'})
    .pipe(
      tap(res => console.log(res)),
      tap(res => console.log(res.headers)),
      tap(res => console.log(res.status))
    )
    .subscribe(todos => this.todos = todos.body);**//TS2322**: Type 'Todo[] | null' is not assignable to type 'Todo[]'.Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Todo[]'.
  }

}
```

1. Why can't I just declare a variable in Angular? Why should I always initialize it with an empty value to go around the error?
2. How can I fix the error 'ts2322'? What's the cause of this error?

Thank you,

Comment: Does this work? .subscribe(todos => this.todos = todos.body ?? []);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have [Strict Property Initialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictPropertyInitialization) (or strict) enabled in your `tsconfig.json`.
With this, you must set all property directly or in the constructor.

If you don't want to assign with an empty array and you know for sure it's going to be initialized, you can use the Non-Null Assertion Operator:

```js
todos!: Todo[];
```

Or you need to make it optional:

```js
todos?: Todo[];
```

Comment: This answer led me to the solution, which was I didn't have a `tsconfig.json` file at all.