# Writing a function that returns an array of type "without null" throws an error Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'NonNull'.(2322)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, null

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71351797/6105259), I have a function that removes `null` elements from an array (but not `undefined`):

```js
// JavaScript
const dropNull = arr => {
    return arr.flatMap((f) => (f === null ? [] : f));
};
```

And now I want to use *TypeScript* to strictly define the types of the function's input and output:

- **input:** any array
- **output:** any array that doesn't contain `null`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63045455/6105259) shows a very similar situation, but opposite to mine: whereas they want to allow `null` but restrict `undefined`, I want to restrict `null` and allow `undefined`. So inspired by the answer I did the reverse tweak:

```js
type NonNull<T> = T extends null ? never : T[];

const dropNull = <T>(arr: T[]): NonNull<T>[] => {
    return arr.flatMap((f) => (f === null ? [] : f));
};
```

But as [this REPL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOxgVwDaoDwBUB8UC8UWUEAHsBAgCYDOUCaqUA-PRAG4QBOUAXEQG0AugG4AsAChJAY0Q1gUKlzhgU6AlGwAaHAAoAhly78swgJT94SRthzCCeAN6SAkFwjBkXBFENcAdABmqPrAALL6YLq6gWYOUDEE+IQM6qz2-LFm4hIAviJAA) shows, I get an error:

> Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'NonNull[]'.
>
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'NonNull'.(2322)

Researching this error I've seen answers [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66217786/6105259), but I couldn't figure out how to adopt it to my case.

Comment: You might have to just manually cast the type to get around this. `return arr.flatMap((f) => (f === null ? [] : f)) as unknown as NonNull<T>[]`.

Comment: The question as written is strange. If it's an array of T, then there shouldn't be any nulls in there unless T includes null in the type. Also, are you expecting an array of arrays here? Because `NotNull` essentially turns `T -> T[]`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for typescript to enforce returning a conditional type, because it's hard to know how your logic corresponds to that type. But I think you're over complicating it, and you can sidestep the issue entirely.

```
const dropNull = <T>(arr: (T | null)[]): T[] => {
    return arr.flatMap((f) => (f === null ? [] : f));
};
```

Here the generic parameter `T` is inferred as a type that does *not* contain `null`. And the argument is an array that can be filled with `T` or `null`.

Then you can simply return non null values from the array and typescript is happy.

```
const numsOrNull = [1,2,null] // (number | null)[]
const nums = dropNull(numsOrNull) // number[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&ssl=6&ssc=46&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgJxABwHIFcA2mYF4YA8AKgHwAUAhgggFwxlEwA+MYWmAlANoC6HdRXnhIwA3gFgAUAEgEAUyjoEYGFQQA6AGaYKUALIVkZMpo7D6mvLnxtsMAPwwhdUxwDcUgL4fJU0JFg2AFsIAHkEDDt8LgBGABoAJjjbTB4YAHp0+mCAIzkEZlZ2bh4-cGgikLx4JDR2MmCwiOKMrNz83iA)

Comment: This plays badly if `T = string[]`.